# PHPmailer custom header set, but not shown on delivery

Tags: php, phpmailer, directadmin, custom-headers

I am using PHPMailer6.2.0 and I am having issues setting the return path.

I have added the custom header via PHPmailer function addCustomHeader()

```
$mail->addCustomHeader("Return-Path", $fromemail);
```

and for debugging I have printed out the header content in \PHPMailer\PHPMailer.php function `mailSend($header, $body)` on line 1794;

```
var_export($header);
die();
```

this prints out the header content before it will be sent and it verifies that the custom header return-path is set correctly, however in action, when i receive an email to my outlook, the header return path callbacks to the domains default email user@domain.com. Perhaps this is not the last place before the email is sent and it gets lost later on?

I am using DirectAdmin as my server manager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stop right there! Senders should *not* set a `return-path` header. That header is added by **the receiver**, and what goes into it is dependent on the SMTP envelope sender, the address that's used in the SMTP `MAIL FROM` command that delivered the message. Setting this header as a sender is a straightforward contravention of the RFCs. So what should you do instead? Set the envelope sender, and in PHPMailer you do that like this:

```
$mail->Sender = $fromemail;
```

Even when you do this, whether the server your'e sending through will accept it is a different matter. For example gmail will not allow you to use anything other than your account username address or predefined aliases, not arbitrary addresses.

Comment: Thanks a 1000! It would have probably took me ages to find this, the return-path is now correct! You are a life saver!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the comment above in mailSend function?
The sender gets turned into a return-path header by the receiver!

```
<?php
    $params = null;
    //This sets the SMTP envelope sender which gets turned into a return-path header by the receiver
    //A space after `-f` is optional, but there is a long history of its presence
    //causing problems, so we don't use one
    //Exim docs: http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-the_exim_command_line.html
    //Sendmail docs: http://www.sendmail.org/~ca/email/man/sendmail.html
    //Qmail docs: http://www.qmail.org/man/man8/qmail-inject.html
    //Example problem: https://www.drupal.org/node/1057954
    // CVE-2016-10033, CVE-2016-10045: Don't pass -f if characters will be escaped.
    if (!empty($this->Sender) && static::validateAddress($this->Sender) && self::isShellSafe($this->Sender)) {
        $params = sprintf('-f%s', $this->Sender);
    }
```

I do not think you should set the return-path header by yourself. I believe PHPMailer uses the sender to handle this automatically. But correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Yes, apparently it does, as the above comment mentions it. I did not notice that function comment and for that I am sorry, probably would have saved some time. But hey? Live and learn, I guess. Thanks for your Input!